# How to add a second registered target (with a different port) to an alb target group pointing at a task definition

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

I started with this shippable tutorial as a base for creating my AWS environment: http://blog.shippable.com/setup-a-container-cluster-on-aws-with-terraform-part-2-provision-a-cluster

Right now I have 2 services running 2 containers each on 2 EC2 instances behind 2 load balancers (1 for each service). I am trying to add a second registered target with a different port to the target group, and point it at one of my containers. The listener was easy to add to the ALB, but I can't seem to figure out how to add a second target to dynamically point to the instance running my service.

In the UI, I can only manually point it to an AWS Instance, not have it dynamically point to whichever instance is running my service.

The following looks like it should work, but since my containers are created within tasks, I don't seem to have access to the container id to point the target_ip at, and it can't be pointed to a service.

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "test" {
  target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.ecs-target-group.arn}"
  target_id        = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.test.id}"
  port             = 5000
}
```

Here's some more terraform code for context:

```
resource "aws_alb" "ecs-load-balancer" {
  name                = "ecs-load-balancer"
  security_groups     = ["${aws_security_group.test_public_sg.id}"]
  subnets             = ["${aws_subnet.test_public_sn_01.id}", "${aws_subnet.test_public_sn_02.id}"]

  tags {
    Name = "ecs-load-balancer"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "ecs-target-group" {
  name                = "ecs-target-group"
  port                = "80"
  protocol            = "HTTP"
  vpc_id              = "${aws_vpc.test_vpc.id}"

  health_check {
      healthy_threshold   = "5"
      unhealthy_threshold = "2"
      interval            = "30"
      matcher             = "200"
      path                = "/"
      port                = "traffic-port"
      protocol            = "HTTP"
      timeout             = "5"
  }

  tags {
    Name = "ecs-target-group"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb-listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.ecs-load-balancer.arn}"
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
      target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.ecs-target-group.arn}"
      type             = "forward"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb-listener-vemcoio" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.ecs-load-balancer.arn}"
  port              = "5000"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.ecs-target-group.arn}"
    type             = "forward"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "test" {
  family                = "test"
  container_definitions = "${data.template_file.test.rendered}"
}

data "template_file" "test" {
  depends_on = ["aws_instance.mongodb_one"]
  template = "${file("task-definitions/test.json")}"

  vars {
    mongo_ip = "${aws_instance.mongodb_one.private_ip}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use the resource `"aws_alb_target_group_attachment"` to attach the target group with the container or task or instance.

You may use below code. It will automatically take care of the dynamic port of the ecs tasks.

Check the last four line of the below code.

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "rc" {
  name       = "rc"
  port       = 80
  protocol   = "HTTP"
  vpc_id     = "${var.vpc_id}"
}
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "rc" {
  listener_arn = "${var.listener_arn}"
  priority     = 100

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.rc.arn}"
  }

  condition {
    field  = "host-header"
    values = ["www.domain.com"]
  }
}
resource "aws_ecs_service" "rc" {
  name    = "${var.name}"
  cluster = "${var.cluster}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.rc.arn}"
  desired_count   = "${var.desired_count}"

  health_check_grace_period_seconds = "${var.health_grace_period}"
  deployment_maximum_percent         = "${var.deployment_maximum_percent}"
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = "${var.deployment_minimum_healthy_percent}"

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.rc.arn}"
    container_name   = "test"
    container_port   = 5000
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have that, but it points to the port 80, which I also need forward. Is there a way to add a second port there?

Comment: There will not be a problem. This is the port the load balancer uses when routing traffic to targets in this target group. 

By default, a load balancer routes requests to its targets using the protocol and port number that you specified when you created the target group. Alternatively, you can override the port used for routing traffic to a target when you register it with the target group.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this will help to listen/forward to 2 different ports.

Comment: This will not forward to 2 different port but 5000(in your case) because you are overwriting the previous port 80 which you have created when you have created the target group. Also, you have to use the host-based routing in this particular case. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The point of my question was to forward to 2 different ports though.

Comment: This will point to any port which your ecs service will decide. If you are using dynamic port functionality of ecs.